# A new session could not be created. (Original error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/0dde512af8b2943ab00684b128adeafb.apk

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, appium

I am Getting Exception when i am running Android app using Appium.`enter code here`    Error  in Appium:  > Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

> ```
> at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:1358:17
> at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:180:9)
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:742:7)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (
>   Original error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/0dde512af8b2943ab00684b128adeafb.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE])","origValue":"Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/0dde512af8b2943ab00684b128adeafb.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 33412.227 ms - 382

Error in Eclipse:Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. 
(Original error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/0dde512af8b2943ab00684b128adeafb.apk

```
public class FootballTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    AppiumDriver driver;


     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi 3S");
     capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
     capabilities.setCapability("app",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/apk/OurField.apk");
     capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.football.oufield");
     capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".LoginActivity");
     driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4788/wd/hub"), capabilities);

     //Username :-   com.football.ourfield:id/edt_username
     driver.findElement(By.id("com.football.ourfield:id/edt_username")).sendKeys("abc");
    //password :-   com.football.ourfield:id/edt_password

     driver.findElement(By.id("com.football.ourfield:id/edt_password")).sendKeys("123456");
     //login :-     com.football.ourfield:id/btn_login

     driver.findElement(By.id("com.football.ourfield:id/btn_login")).click();


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Log clearly states "[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE])". One of the possible reason might be the device is already installed with a updated version of the app that you are currently trying to install. For eg, the device may already have ourFieldV1.1 and you are trying to install ourFieldV1.0.

Try uninstalling the existing app and re run the script.

**Note** - I tried to comment my thoughts in your question but i didn't have enough privileges.